# Como hacer una insercion multiple en PHP+MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

```
<label>Experiencia</label>
<ul class="checkbox-grid"> 
    <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vitae"); // Alternativa 1
    mysqli_query ($link,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $c=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM experiencia_interesado order by id_experiencia_interesado");
    while($d=mysqli_fetch_object($c))
    {
     echo'<li><input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="'.$d->id_experiencia_interesado.'"/><label>'.$d->nombre_experiencia.'</label></li>';
    }
    ?>  </li> </ul>
```

En el codigo anterior cargo un checkbox de manera dinamica, mi situacion es que no he logrado hacer un insert de los checkbox que selecciono, agradeceria si alguien me da guia de como lo puedo hacer. De antemano gracias

Comment: No se entiende qué quieres decir con *hacer un insert de los checkbox*  ¿?  ¿De qué forma lo estás intentando, cuál es el fallo?

Comment: @A.Cedano mi intencion es la de guardar en una tabla de la base de datos los ID de los Checkbox seleccionados.

Comment: Pero... debes recuperar primero cuáles checkbox fueron seleccionados y luego pasarlos al servidor para hacer la inserción (preferiblemente por medio de Ajax).  ¿De qué manera intentas eso? Aquí hay varios ejemplos de como hacerlo.